# integrate form in others froms in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a simple question about form in Symfony2,how to integrate a form in other forms when I want to,the way to declare it?

My form is just a multiselect field and I want to use it in others forms,also I don't want to use it with :

```
{{ form_widget(form.multiselectform) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed forms within other forms. See the [Cookbook page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) on this subject.

Comment: so whe don't have any solution to use for in other forms just with "embedded forms"?*